# How to perform a 'selective strip' on a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, strip

Let's say I have a df:

```
 Name A
 'John ' 
 'John and Mary ' 
 'Harry '
 'Paul ' 
 'Paul and Harry '
```

How would I remove the trailing whitespace from each of the dataframe values without removing the spaces between 'John and Mary' so...the new df would look like:

```
 Name A
 'John' 
 'John and Mary' 
 'Harry'
 'Paul' 
 'Paul and Harry'
```

I have tried str.split method but this interferes with the multi-name values..Also tried the replace method. Maybe some sort of indexing of the dataframe values like [:-1]. This could work?
not sure what else to try?

Comment: I think you need `df['Name A'].str.strip()` only

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) if need remove `'` and whitespaces from left and right sides:

```
df['Name A'] = df['Name A'].str.strip("' ")
print (df)
           Name A
0            John
1   John and Mary
2           Harry
3            Paul
4  Paul and Harry
```

If need remove only whitespaces from `right` side use [`rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) - parameter is not necessary, becasue `whitespace` is default:

```
df['Name A'] = df['Name A'].str.rstrip()
```

Comment: I am getting Series has no attribute rstrip()  but str.strp("' ) works, thanks.

Comment: Maybe some old version of pandas, [`rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try `.rstrip()`, this will strip all the spaces on the right side of the string